# Nuxt JS Vuex setting data not reflected in real-time when loading page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt JS 2.9 application I'm using Vuex to save data and retrieve in my layout. I'm setting data into my Vuex store on a per page basis, it's working, but for some reason is requiring me to refresh the page of the new page to see my data otherwise it shows old data.

For example, on my **Homepage** I'm setting:

```js
mounted () {
  this.$store.commit('toolbar/setToolbar', {
    name: 'Homepage'
  })
}
```

And on my **Settings** page:

```js
mounted () {
  this.$store.commit('toolbar/setToolbar', {
    name: 'Settings'
  })
}
```

this is going into my Vuex as follows:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  toolbarData: [{
    name: 'Homepage'
  }]
})

export const mutations = {

  /*
   * Toolbar data
   */
  setToolbar (state, data) {
    const settings = {
      name: data.name != null ? data.name : ''
    }

    state.toolbarData[0] = settings
  }

}
```

And when I change between the **Homepage** and **Settings** page the state is updated, but isn't reflected in real-time in my page?

I've tried changing the lifecycle hook from `mounted` to `created` and `beforeCreate` in the hope that it would commit to the store and be ready before the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of caveats of reactivity in Vue. You can read more about it over here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

For you to solve the issue you can replace the whole array:

```
setToolbar (state, data) {
    const settings = {
      name: data.name != null ? data.name : ''
    }

    state.toolbarData = [settings]
  }
```

Or set only what you need to set:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

etToolbar (state, data) {
    const settings = {
      name: data.name != null ? data.name : ''
    }

    Vue.set(state.toolbarData, 1, settings);
  }
```